# Valid / invalid moments in Generalized Method of Moments (GMM)

Tags: references, median, moments, generalized-moments, mode

I'm preparing to conduct an estimation procedure using GMM (Generalized Method of Moments), and I'm in the process of selecting my moments.  This got me thinking, can I use non-statistical moments as my "moments" (i.e., median, mode, other functions of the data)?  Will the resulting estimator still enjoy the consistency, efficiency, and asymptotic normality that the GMM estimator typically enjoys?  References addressing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what you mean by a "nonstatistical" moment?

Comment: By nonstatistical moment I mean a feature of the data that is not the first moment, second moment, etc.  Some examples would include median, mode, and range.

Comment: You could search for minimum distance estimation.